# Python requested API showing error while decoding json

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am working with python "requests" module. I have accessed the web application using the get command but this is showing successful authentication, but still this is unable to decode few of the websites.

I have tried the commands like

```
response=requests.get('url details')
print(response)              ## for this I m getting correct result
print(response.json())       ## I m lagging here, where this showing some
```

kind                                       #                               of error

```
response=requests.get(url)

print(response.json())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "C:\Users\kahamed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kahamed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\kahamed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\kahamed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 2)
```

Comment: And if you do `print(r.content)`, do you see json?

Comment: response.status_code == 200 ?   response.text is json?

Answer (score -1):

You can Try the following

```
import requests
response = requests.get('url details')
data = response.json()
```

or

```
requests.get('url details').json()
```

or

```
import json
data = requests.get('url details').text
data = json.loads(data)
```

hope it helps

For testing purpose I've used the following URL 
https://github.com/timeline.json and the three above mentioned scenario worked for me.